# Getting java.io.EOFException on Spring Kafka configuration with SSL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am working on Kafka Streams code using Spring cloud Stream.
Maven version - Spring Boot 2.0.2 Release
Apache kafka-streams - 1.1.0
Apache kafka-client - 1.1.0.

configuration -

```
spring:
  profiles: dev, test
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          autoCreateTopics: false
          auto-add-partitions: false
          brokers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
          configuration:
            security.protocol: SSL
            ssl.truststore-location: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION}
            ssl.truststore-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}
            ssl.keystore-location: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION}
            ssl.keystore-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
            ssl.key-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD}
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
    properties:
      security.protocol: ${SPRING_KAFKA_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL:SSL}
    ssl:
      truststore-location: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION}
      truststore-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}
      keystore-location: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION}
      keystore-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
      key-password: ${SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD}
```

Exception -

```
Removing node node1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) from least loaded node selection: is-blacked-out: false, in-flight-requests: 1
Removing node node2:9092 (id: -2 rack: null) from least loaded node selection: is-blacked-out: false, in-flight-requests: 0
Removing node node3:9092 (id: -5 rack: null) from least loaded node selection: is-blacked-out: false, in-flight-requests: 0
Found least loaded node node3:9092 (id: -3 rack: null)
Connection with node3/<ipaddress> disconnected

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:147) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:235) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:196) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:557) [kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:495) [kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:424) [kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460) [kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
```

It appears ssl configuration is not getting set for ProducerConfig and ConsumerConfig while it is populated for AdminCLientCOnfig. This looks like an issue -

```
2018-06-14 13:15:33.652  INFO 91844 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
    security.protocol = SSL
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.location = //keystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.location = //truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]

  2018-06-14 13:15:35.586  INFO 91844 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null

  2018-06-14 13:15:35.609  INFO 91844 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
```

Comment: Stack trace doesn't point to anything Spring. Could you please update with he full stack trace?

Comment: I saw a similar issue reported in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/290. Not sure if this issue is version specific.

Comment: No; that was a specific mismatch between the client and broker versions; this is something different; doesn't look related to Spring at all.

Comment: I updated the original comment with more details, SSL configurations are not getting set for ProducerConfig and ConsumerConfig while it is populated for AdminClientConfig. This looks like an issue. Any help on how to pass in same ssl configuration for kafka producer and consumer while working with kafka streams.

Comment: Adding it to kafka.streams.binder.configuration worked - I didn't find it any documentation. I thought existing spring.cloud.stream.binder might take care of it - spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.security.protocol: SSL